# How to import Telegram post views to Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, telegram

I have a list of Telegram post links, and I want to use a formula like IMPORTXML to automatically import their post views to Google Sheet.

I know this formula import the number of subscribers to Google Sheet:

`=value(substitute(regexextract(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='tgme_page_extra']"),"[0-9 ]+")," ",""))`

But I couldn't change it to something that imports the post views.
Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since Telegram uses Iframe to display the post on the web page, you should use the Iframe's target URL in your URL list (by adding `?embed=1` to URLs. And then you can use this formula:

`=IMPORTXML(A1, "//span[contains(@class, 'tgme_widget_message_views')]")`

[image]